# Set up INTL in Mac Catalina

Tags: php, macos, macos-catalina

Im installing cakephp 4 on my macbook pro running omn Catalina, PHP 7.3
how do to setup and enable INTL ?

Comment: To setup a native apache/php/mysql environement it was helpful for me to use https://www.macports.org/. You can install any custom PHP extention you like (if  available). But that's just a hint. Quite a lot of docs to read.

Comment: There's nearly 100 results here on StackOverflow if you search for `mac php intl`. While getting that working is a prerequisite for CakePHP, the actual installation of the extension has nothing to do with Cake.